# can subcontractors claim contractors work?

Tags: web-development, business, freelancing

If I am subcontracting from a company. Am I able to claim the work as if I were doing for the client themselves. In other words....

if Client A ask Company A to do some web development. and Company A sub contracts out to Company B. Can Company B claim they did work for Client A. Or must they say they did work for Company A ?

I am building my site and I want to release all the work I did for 1 company who subcontracted me. but I dont want to get into any legal issues.

Comment: I've been in this situation a few times, unless the contract specifies otherwise I would say **no**. Client A may only know they hired Company A, not knowing about Company B's involvement.

Answer (score 3):

Why not just cover the bases?

```
We built Product A for Client A, while subcontracted to Company A
```

That way you are fully truthful and if anyone wants to verify your work they can follow the trail, it wouldn't look good if Client B talked to Client A and Client A tells them it was really Company A that did the work - they've never heard of you.

Answer (score 2):

This is known as a prime contract vs subcontractor.

The prime contract is Client A -> Company A

Company B is a subcontractor to Company A.

If you are company B, then you work for company A.

HOWEVER if you want to put names and ownership relations onto web sites or into source code files  or things like that then you should be asking Company A AND ALSO Client A what they want done.

In a perfect world this sort of thing would all be in the written contract from Client A to Company A, including flow-down clauses. Seeing as that does not seem to be the case, you should ask what they want done.